My old LG monitor's screen goes fully black on Custom Picture Mode when very dark images are displayed
I have an LG 23MP55, and when I run the "Custom" Picture Mode, the screen goes fully black when a very dark image is displayed (such as a fullscreen image of a black solid square, a scene in a video with very low levels of lighting such as in an underground cave, etc).
It seems to go away by changing to another Picture Mode setting such as Cinema, but the problem is that those modes have certain adjustments that I don't like (Cinema messes up the gamma level, for example).
People online attribute it to the Super Energy Saving option, but that's always turned off. For curiosity's sake I actually tried to turn it on, and oddly enough that actually prevents this issue from happening. But I don't need energy saving and I feel like this isn't the intended behavior.
How do I get rid of this and make it so that the screen stays on at all times in the Custom mode?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

LG 23MP55 seems to have two input: D-Sub (analog) and HDMI. Which one do you use?

@Robert I use a HDMI connection.
